# Display the entire row in the SELECT output

Tags: mysql

I am a beginner in SQL, this is maybe a dumb question...

**Table 1 (guide_book) :**

| ID | Table ID | Column A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | a |
| 1 | 0 | b |
| 2 | 0 | c |
| 3 | 0 | d |

**Table 2 (adding) :**

| ID | Table ID | Column A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | b |
| 1 | 1 | c |
| 2 | 1 | d |
| 3 | 1 | e |

**Query**

```
SELECT Column A 
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Table ID, Column A 
  FROM guide_book 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ID, Table ID, Column A 
  FROM adding
) temp
GROUP BY Column A 
having count(*)=1;
```

**Output**

| Column A |
| --- |
| a |
| e |

**Desired output**

| ID | Table ID | Column A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | a |
| 3 | 1 | e |

Since I have big table I need to know where are the results and in which table.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your query groups by `Column A` and filters out unique values, but it doesn't keep track of the original `ID` and `Table ID`. To get the desired output, you can use Common Table Expressions (CTEs).

First, create a CTE named `Combined` that unions both tables (`guide_book` and `adding`). Then, create another CTE named `Counts` that counts the occurrences of each value in `Column A`.

Finally, perform a SELECT query that joins the `Combined` and `Counts` CTEs. Filter the rows where the count is 1 to get the unique values along with their `ID` and `Table ID`.

Here's an example:

```sql
WITH Combined AS (
  SELECT ID, "Table ID", "Column A" FROM guide_book
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ID, "Table ID", "Column A" FROM adding
),
Counts AS (
  SELECT "Column A", COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM Combined
  GROUP BY "Column A"
)
SELECT c.ID, c."Table ID", c."Column A"
FROM Combined c
JOIN Counts ct ON c."Column A" = ct."Column A"
WHERE ct.cnt = 1;
```

This should give you the desired output with `ID`, `Table ID`, and `Column A` for the unique values.